# Modifying a code for calculator in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem when I have performed an operation between two numbers and instead of a new operation I press a number, the number sticks to the result, here is an example - I enter 5+5 the result is 10, but then when I click on a number button, for example 5 it becomes 105,but I want to clear the result and start a new operation. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!Here is the code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import math   
def button_1_is_Clicked():  
    global var
    var = var + "1"  
    the_data.set(var)
def button_2_is_Clicked():  
    global var  
    var = var + "2"  
    the_data.set(var)    
def button_3_is_Clicked():  
    global var  
    var = var + "3"  
    the_data.set(var)  
def button_4_is_Clicked():  
    global var  
    var = var + "4"  
    the_data.set(var)   
def button_5_is_Clicked():  
    global var  
    var = var + "5"  
    the_data.set(var)   
def button_6_is_Clicked():  
    global var  
    var = var + "6"  
    the_data.set(var)  
def button_7_is_Clicked():  
    global var  
    var = var + "7"  
    the_data.set(var)    
def button_8_is_Clicked():  
    global var  
    var = var + "8"  
    the_data.set(var)   
def button_9_is_Clicked():  
    global var  
    var = var + "9"  
    the_data.set(var)   
def button_0_is_Clicked():  
    global var  
    var = var + "0"  
    the_data.set(var)   
def button_Add_is_Clicked():  
    global A  
    global var  
    global operator
    global prevous_operator
    A = float(var)  
    operator = "+"  
    var = var + "+"
    the_data.set(var)
def button_Sub_is_Clicked():  
    global A  
    global var  
    global operator
    global prevous_operator
    A = float(var)  
    operator = "-"  
    var = var + "-"  
    the_data.set(var)
def button_Mul_is_Clicked():  
    global A  
    global var  
    global operator
    global prevous_operator
    A = float(var)  
    operator = "*"  
    var = var + "*"  
    the_data.set(var)
def button_Div_is_Clicked():  
    global A  
    global var  
    global operator
    global prevous_operator
    A = float(var)  
    operator = "/"  
    var = var + "/"  
    the_data.set(var)
def button_Equal_is_Clicked():  
    global A  
    global var  
    global operator  
    A = float(var)  
    operator = "="  
    var = var + "="  
    the_data.set(var)
def button_Sqrt_is_Clicked():
    global A
    global var
    global operator
    global prevous_operator
    A=float(var)
    operator="sqrt"
    var="√"+var
    the_data.set(var)
def button_Square_is_Clicked():
    global A
    global var
    global operator
    A=float(var)
    operator="square"
    var=var+"*"+var
    the_data.set(var)
def button_Percent_is_Clicked():  
    global A  
    global var  
    global operator
    global prevous_operator
    A = float(var)  
    operator = "%"  
    var = var + "%"  
    the_data.set(var)
def button_Inv_is_Clicked():  
    global A  
    global var  
    global operator
    global prevous_operator
    A = float(var)  
    operator = "1/x"  
    var = "1/"+var  
    the_data.set(var)
    var = ""
def button_C_is_Clicked():  
    global A  
    global var  
    global operator  
    var = ""  
    A = 0  
    operator = ""  
    the_data.set("0")

def button_PlusMinus_is_Clicked():  
    global A  
    global var  
    global operator  
    A = float(var)  
    operator = "+/-"  
    var = var + "+/-"  
    the_data.set(var) 

def button_MC_is_Clicked():  
    global A  
    global var  
    global operator  
    operator = "MC"  
    the_data.set("") 

def button_MR_is_Clicked():  
    global A  
    global var  
    global operator  
    operator = "MR"  
    the_data.set("") 

def button_MS_is_Clicked():  
    global A  
    global var  
    global operator  
    operator = "MS"  
    the_data.set("") 

def button_MPlus_is_Clicked():  
    global A  
    global var  
    global operator  
    operator = "M+"  
    the_data.set("") 

def button_MMinus_is_Clicked():  
    global A  
    global var  
    global operator
    operator = "M-"  
    the_data.set("")

def button_CE_is_Clicked():
    global var
    var = var[:-1]
    if var == "":
        the_data.set("0")
    else:
        the_data.set(var)


    

var = ""
A = 0
operator = ""
memory = 0

def res():
    global A
    global operator
    global var
    global memory
    var2 = var
    try:
        if operator == "+":
            a = float((var2.split("+")[1]))
            A += a
            the_data.set(A)
            var = str(A)
        elif operator == "-":
            a = float((var2.split("-")[1]))
            A -= a
            the_data.set(A)
            var = str(A)
            var = ""
        elif operator == "*":
            a = float((var2.split("*")[1]))
            A *= a
            the_data.set(A)
            var = str(A)
            var = ""
        elif operator == "/":
            a = float((var2.split("/")[1]))
            if a == 0:
                raise ZeroDivisionError
            else:
                A /= a
                the_data.set(A)
                var = str(A)
                var = ""
        elif operator == "sqrt":
            if A < 0:
                raise ValueError("Cannot take square root of a negative number.")
            A = math.sqrt(A)
            the_data.set(A)
            var = str(A)
            var = ""
        elif operator == "square":
            a=float((var2.split("*")[1]))
            A*=A
            the_data.set(A)
            var = str(A)
            var = ""
        elif operator == "%":
            a = float(var2.split("%")[0])
            A *= (a/100)
            the_data.set(A)
            var = str(A)
            var = ""
        elif operator == "1/x":
            if A == 0:
                raise ZeroDivisionError("Cannot divide by zero.")
            A = 1/A
            the_data.set(A)
            var = str(A)
            var = ""
        elif operator == "+/-":
            A = -A
            the_data.set(A)
            var = str(A)
            var = ""
        elif operator == "MC":
            memory = 0
        elif operator == "MR":
            A = memory
            the_data.set(A)
        elif operator == "MS":
            memory = A
        elif operator == "M+":
            memory += A
        elif operator == "M-":
            memory -= A
        elif operator == "CE":
            if len(var) > 1:
                var = var[:-1]
                A = float(var)
                the_data.set(A)
            else:
                var = ""
                A = 0
                the_data.set(0)
       

    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", str(e))
        var = ""
    except ValueError as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", str(e))
        var = ""
```

I have tried everything

Comment: High-level languages like Python and Javascript would interpret the action you want to do. In your example, you want to use `+` operation. When you add two numbers it is easy, the interpreter would do an addition. But what if you use `+` sign on two strings? Then it would concatenate them. This means two strings would append to each other. You are adding two strings. BTW, using global variables is not a good practice.

Comment: That's because all the `button_x_is_Clicked()` functions treat `var` as a string.  Adding the string "10" and the string "5" gives the string "105", because that's how string concatenation works.  If you want integer addition, don't use strings!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change scripts architecture (I think, you need to do it!) , you will need to clear the_data after you have displayed result. I think, you need one more variable (but don't recommend to set global), where you set displayed_result, and if you press number and displayed_result is true, you will need to clear all in the_data, but if you press operator, you will need to clear all before equal (something like: n = var.split("="); the_data.set(n if len(n) < 2 else n[1])) and set n[1] as A.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).